# Laravel - post requests error 500 (working on localhost not on production)

Tags: php, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, axios

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`, `vue.js` and `axios`. The server relies on LEMP Stack 16.04

Before going any further, I'd like to mention that everything is working well on my `localhost`. Issues occur in `production` site.

#### Situation

Any requests `axios.post` seem to finish with an error `500`.

If I do `axios.get('test')` it is working.
If I do `axios.post('test')` I get `500 (Internal Server Error)`. and if I preview the result I could see `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

#### bootstrap.js

```
...
...

axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

...
...
```

#### Error printed

```
(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ShareErrorsFromSession.php (line 49)
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in StartSession.php (line 64)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php (line 37)
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in EncryptCookies.php (line 59)
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php (line 576)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php (line 535)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 513)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 174)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 149)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 53)
```

#### Localhost (working)

[image: Local host]

#### Production (not working)

[image]

#### Question

What should I do ?

Comment: Compare the `env` files on localhost and prod.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the permission on the folder `laravel/sessions`